# how can i be exporting Strapi's content data to excel

Tags: node.js, npm, export-to-excel, strapi

I'm a newbie to strapi and nodejs and i'm using strapi version 4, trying to find a way i can be exporting some data from content-types to excel.
tried the [excel-export plugin](https://npmmirror.com/package/strapi-plugin-excel-export) and it didn't show on the UI until i edited the `config/plugins.js`

```
module.exports = () => ({
    excelexport: {
        resolve: './plugins/excel-export',
        enabled: true,
    }
})
```

and it showed up on the plugin list but not functioning

[this is my dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbw9z.png)

Any ideas would be helpful.